# What are the dinosaur equivalents?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

I need to pull together a list of dinosaur equivalents for D&D by name, what dinosaur they are equivalent to, and ideally book.

I know the various monster manuals and other books have a bunch of dinosaur equivalents.  I don't have all the books but I do have D&D insider which has a major weakness of no pictures. I have this big need for a plateau filled with dinosaurs (my daughter has been making tokens with dinosaurs stamped on them).

Comment: Nota bene, in case anyone doesn't realize: the various drakes are generally dinosaur cognates.

Comment: Huh. That'll make things easier. I was looking for the various creatures from Eberron, like the *fastieth*.

Comment: I don't know about 4e ... but I could have sworn that 3e and before had actual dinosaurs in one of the monster manuals. Makes me wish I wouldn't have sold all my 3e and before stuff.

Comment: @Scott -- yep! See also http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dinosaur.htm.

Comment: @Bryan -- Excellent !!! glad my memory isn't failing me yet !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Behemoths are the D&D4 dinosauroids. I'm not sure they have obvious equivalents in all cases.

- Bone-Crown - Pachycephalosaurus? - mm3
- Skinwing - One of the pteradactyl types - mm3
- Bloodspike - Stegosaurus? -mm1
- Macetail - Anklosaurus! -mm1
- Tri-Horn - Triceratops -Adventurer's Vault
- Spirehorn - Like a.. really big Triceratops? -mm3

I'd also add in Fastieth (it's an Ebberon monster, but it's a nice little velociraptor guy)

Other ideas include a reskinned Destrachan, certain drakes, and maybe even reskin stirge's as pleistocene mosquitos. ;)

Also [see this thread.](http://www.enworld.org/forum/4e-discussion/274373-d-d-4th-edition-dinosaurs.html) The Fang Titan Drake (mm2) is highly recommended as a stand-in for a T-Rex.

Answer (score 0):

The older editions (AD&D 2, D&D Cyclopedia) have explicit Dinosaur Entries.
D&D Cyclopedia

- Dinosaur, Aquatic, Small
- Dinosaur, Aquatic, Large
- Dinosaur, Aquatic, Armored
- Dinosaur, Land Carnivore, Small (raptors)
- Dinosaur, Land Carnivore, Large (tyranosaurs)
- Dinosaur, Land Carnivore, Flying (Pterodactyls)
- Dinosaur, Land Herbivore, Small
- Dinosaur, Land Herbivore, Medium
- Dinosaur, Land Herbivore, Armored (Stegosaurs)
- Dinosaur, Land Herbivore, Large (Sauropods)

None of them are explicit links in Cyclopedia, but the parenthesis are my guess based upon description matches.

Answer (score 0):

D&D 3.5e Monster Manual has a whole section on dinosaurs.

The section contains:

- Deinonychus
- Elasmosaurus
- Megaraptor
- Triceratops
- Tyrannosaurus

I don't know if there are any others in there that are closely based on but not quite dinosaurs.

Comment: Just noticed this is the same list that is covered in the link in the comments. Hope it's still useful as an answer.